# Why is Edward Newgate called Whitebeard?

Tags: one-piece, japanese-language

Why do they call him "Whitebeard"?

He doesn't even have a beard!

[image: Whitebeard]

Comment: lol, that trollface whitebeard

Comment: LOL, that last image is funny. :)

Comment: Language - I love it. In some languages, that's called a beard, too, for example German (Schnurr*bart*, Oberlippen*bart*).

Comment: Imagine the disaster if they call him "WHITEMOUSTACHE".. lol

Comment: @maseru For laughs, here you can read the disaster on [a page from chapter 133](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WfTSi.jpg), where the name originally was translated as "moustache" as in "The Black Moustache Pirates destroyed Drum island."

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Edward Newgate's nickname in Japanese is Shirohige (shiro = white, hige = facial hair). Japanese does not distinguish between beard and moustache<sup>1</sup>. However, a literal translation *White Facial Hair* sounds a pretty poor nickname for one of the World's strongest pirates, and even sounds comedic. Whitemoustache isn't much better either. Whitebeard has a nice ring to it.

Also, [fairy-tail](/questions/tagged/fairy-tail)'s Lucy's nickname for the [Celestial Spirit King](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Celestial_Spirit_King) is "hige-oyaji" (translated as moustache-man, in context), and he has only a moustache, which suggests that "hige" is used to refer to both moustache and beard in Japanese.

---

<sup>1: Google Translate says that "Beard" is "Agohige", and "Moustache" is "Kuchihige". However, they did not call him "Shirokuchihige" in the original, so the distinction seems to be not widely used.</sup>

Comment: `However, a literal translation "White Facial Hair"` lol, +1 just for that

Comment: i think also the decision to use Whitebeard in translation was also reinforced by Blackbeard, a well known pirate, after all, you can't really have a pirate series without some sort of reference too him, even if it's a change to the first part of his name

Answer (score 14):

Why is Blackbeard called Blackbeard when he only has perma-stubble? Whitebeard´s flawless mustache is manlier than a thousand normal beards.

And I quote:

> A beard is the collection of hair that grows on the chin, upper lip,
>   cheeks and neck of human beings.

A mustache is also a beard.

Comment: *"A mustache is also a beard"* - We all know that's not true; that definition is just poor...

Comment: This definition (from Wikipedia) says it grows on the chin, lip, cheeks, AND neck. I believe that means simultaneously, especially given their [first image of it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Incredibeard.jpg). xD

Comment: strong beard dont grow on chins, they move to the upper levels.

Answer (score 2):

When the manga was being fan-translated, the translator left a note about how the name in japanese could be translated as white mustache or white beard.  His words went something like, "Who wants to be White Mustach when you can be White Beard."